# Can you recommend a good schematic or module of a Bluetooth + Wi-Fi combo?

Tags: pcb-design, bluetooth, antenna, wifi, pcb-antenna

I have found couple Bluetooth+Wi-Fi modules, but they are in the $20-$40 range - which is, for my opinion, too expensive. I am interested in seeing/reviewing a finished (as in proved to work without problems) schematic of a combo of bluetooth and Wi-Fi modules.

Even if it is not a combo, then two separate schematics - which can be safely integrated. Also, if I would to have them both on one PCB, can I use a single PCB trace antenna? (only one is on at a time).

Lastly, what would you recommend - trace PCB antenna? or chip antenna?

Thanks

Comment: $20-$40 is crazy cheap for any production volumes smaller then many millions of parts. How cheap do you expect this to be? You need a pretty significant amount of CPU power to run a WiFi or BT stack, and a complex radio.

Comment: the modules i seen had only the chipset and antenna. nothing more. maybe you are willing to give me an overview on wifi/bluetooth design?

Comment: If by chipset, do you mean a whole module? (e.g. a PCB with multiple ICs that you mount onto your PCB). I don't think there are many single-chip ICs that can do Wifi. Bluetooth, yes. Bluetooth is a lot more approachable then WiFi. Do you really need WiFi?

Comment: Same reason that a mobile devices needs both. Its just more options. I would have loved to see how Samsung Mobile, for example, implements Wi-Fi and Bluetooth combos. I tried to find their schematics onlines but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For high volume stuff like cellphones and tablets, Wifi and Bluetooth are about 2 square millimeters on the main SOC. See, for example Qualcomm's Snapdragon 600 marketing information http://www.qualcomm.com/snapdragon/processors/600

TI has some interesting modules for doing this

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Wireless_Connectivity_Platforms?DCMP=wtbu_ecs&HQS=connectivitywiki

that might work as examples.